# Formula to combine similar rows but sum values from 1 column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have data in a format like the following (qty is distributed among warehouses):

[image: Starting data]

I would like to get output like this (sum the qty across warehouses):

[image: Ending data]

Can this be done using an Excel or Google Sheets formula?  I'm not real familiar with how to setup a VBA function, so a formula would be excellent if it's possible.  Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like a pivot table...

Comment: Yes, a pivot table also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)

Put this array formula and standard formula in E2:F2 and fill down.

```
'array formula in E2
=INDEX(A$2:A$99, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(E$1:E1, A$2:A$99), 0))
'standard formula in F2
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, E2)
```

[image]

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=query(A:C, "select A, sum(C) where A <> '' group by A label sum(C) 'qty'")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIFs

```
=sumifs($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,$E2)
```

Put that in F2 and drag down

Or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$7=$E2),$C$2:$C$7)
```

Answer (score 1):

in F2 :

```
=SUMIF(A:A,E2,C:C)
```

and in F3 :

```
=SUMIF(A:A,E3,C:C)
```